# Independent variable with 4 classes using in a GLM: different OR for same comparison (AB - BA)

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I am inexperienced in using Rstudio and data-analysis.

I want to perform a Generalized Logistic Regression, using an independent variable with 4 classes: 0,1,2a,2b  and a dependent variable that I want to predict, with yes or no (1,0)

Finally, I figured how to change the reference variable in order to to let all the 4 classes be the reference once. As a result, you will get a Odds Ratio for class 1 when the reference is class 0, but also for class 0 when the reference is class 1.

My question: shouldn't the OR be the same for both combination (different reference setting)?
In fact, the P values are the same.

The image I attached shows the coefficients of the 4 GLM models I created. The other, shows the odds ratio's and a colour map for the same combinations I thought would have the same values.

[image]
[image]

I tried to search the answer on the internet, but could not find something that helps me. I expect a reaction of someone that can confirm things are going wrong, or have advice.

Comment: This is more of a statistical question than a programming question. But the results look as expected. The odds ratios are the odds ratios of each level versus the intercept. If you change which level acts as the intercept, then the odds ratios will change. The p values for the pairwise comparisons will stay the same.

Comment: Oké thankyou very much for your answer. So If I understand correclty, the odds ratio will also change when reference is 0 and you look at class 1 and when reference is 1 and you look at class 0

Comment: Yes, the odds ratio change when you change the reference level and the mathematical relationship is very simple. Note for example that 1/1.83 ≈ 5.45e-01 (you have a typo there which you can also notice because 5.45e+01 = 54.5 is not inside the corresponding confidence interval), 1/7.00 ≈ 1.43e-01 and so on. The numeric difference is only due to the rounding. [Also, there are easier way to extract all the pairwise comparisons from a single model. No need to fit one model for each level of the categorical predictor.]

Comment: @dipetkov Alright, thankyou very much! What kind of test or method do you recommend.. A pairwise t-test?

Comment: You haven't explained what the data you have and what question you are trying to answer by analyzing the data, so I have no idea what test or method would be appropriate.

Comment: I want to predict a result of an intervention when a type of class of tumor is visible on a scan. So the dependent variable has 1 or 0 (correct, false) and the independent variable exists of 4 different classes, 0,1,2a,2b. And I want to answer if one of the class is a better predictor than the other class. @dipetkov

Comment: From the data you have, you could study the probability of 1 for each of the four classes. You can also look at the 6 pairwise comparisons for the 4 classes (as you've already done). Note that you have to adjust the p-values for multiple comparisons (which you haven't done yet). This is very different from whether "one of the class is a better predictor than the other class", which is actually a strange question to ask for tumor classes; after all a cancer patient suffers from a particular type of tumor and no-one gets to decide which which type that would be.